# How to retrieve Extensions from Elastix server using external PHP file?

Tags: php, mysql, asterisk, pbx, elastix

How can we get extensions   from Elastix server using external PHP file?

Comment: What type of extension you mean? Dialplan extension, sip extension,other?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by querying the mysql database Elastix from your PHP.

```
select extension,name from users where ( extension IN (Select DISTINCT id from sip) or extension IN 
(Select distinct id from iax)) order by name;
```

With this query you have the extension and the name of your extensions.

Enjoy!